# Join only first matching record from joining table without duplicate

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, 1. (inbox) keep delivery reports, 2. (outbox) keep send SMS. I can't add foreign key, and change datebase structure.

#### inbox

```
id    number       smsdate
--    ----------   -------------------
1     600600600    2013-08-16 11:51:18
2     700600600    2013-08-16 11:51:16
3     600600600    2013-08-16 11:51:14
4     900600600    2013-08-16 11:51:12
```

#### outbox

```
id      number       processed_date
---     ----------   -------------------
167     600600600    2013-08-16 10:51:10
288     700600600    2013-08-16 09:51:10
356     600600600    2013-08-16 08:51:10
473     900600600    2013-08-16 07:51:10
536     600600600    2013-08-16 06:51:10
```

I would now join the report of sent messages. I can do it in such a way that comparing the number and date of dispatch of the table outbox, with the same number and the nearest date of receipt of the table inbox. I am sure that the reports will be in order.

If i use

```
SELECT outbox.id, inbox.id, outbox.number, inbox.number, 
   outbox.processed_date, inbox.smsdate FROM outbox
LEFT JOIN inbox ON inbox.number= outbox.number 
   AND inbox.smsdate >= outbox.processed_date
GROUP BY outbox.id
ORDER BY outbox.id DESC;
```

I'm getting strange results and reports are duplicated. For if I have 3 sent, and 2 received, for the same number, it should be one empty. And instead of a blank for the latter, it duplicates my previous one.

I tried to add.

```
GROUP BY outbox.id, inbox.id
```

But it was even worse.

It is a way to solve this?

Desired output:

#### output

```
outbox.id    inbox.id
---------    ----------  
   167         NULL 
   288          2 
   356          1
   473          4 
   536          3
```

Comment: Why you are grouping it with outbox.id?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I do not know, I tried them all. I just want to connect to the table so that the closest date to the same number of inbox, was matched to the id of the outbox, but only once, because if it has been used for this number, then let him seek another with the closest date.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use a correlated subquery to get the `inbox` id, and then join back to the `inbox` table to pull the columns you want:

```
select o.id, iid, o.number, i.number, o.processed_date, i.smsdate
from (select o.*,
             (select i.id
              from inbox i
              where i.number = o.number and
                    i.smsdate >= o.processed_date
              order by i.sms.date
              limit 1
             ) iid
      from outbox o
     ) o left outer join
     inbox i
     on o.iid = i.id
ORDER BY outbox.id DESC;
```

Comment: Look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b47b/5  I have only 11 reports, and 23 sends. But results give me 20 reports to sends, more duplicate. One report can only fit into one message, the one whose date is closest to the date of dispatch.

Comment: @Damonsson . . . I think your description of the problem is incomplete.  The only description is that the closest date is the one to be used, not that you are looking for some sort of one-to-one match between the tables.  And, I have no idea what a "report" is.  Your tables are called "inbox" and "outbox".

Comment: The table outbox are outgoing SMS and Table inbox are delivery reports for the messages. I just want to match the delivery report to the SMS. However, I have no idea how to do it. If I, for example, five delivery reports for the phone number and 10 sent messages to this number. I want that for these five have assigned delivery report, and for the rest just null, taking into account the fact that the report must be dated later than the sent message.

Comment: @Damonsson . . . In your SQL Fiddle data, outbox rows 3 and 4 both match back to inbox id 5 -- as my query finds.  I'm tempted to say that you should just delete this question, and formulate another one that actually explains what you want to accomplish (along with the SQL Fiddle).  If you just modify this question, you do a disservice to anyone who has answered this version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT outbox.id, inbox.id, outbox.number, inbox.number, 
   outbox.processed_date, inbox.smsdate FROM outbox
LEFT JOIN inbox ON inbox.number= outbox.number 
   WHERE inbox.smsdate >= outbox.processed_date
```